# Using loc with a list from a DatetimeIndex returns error

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex, pandas-loc

When I create a DatetimeIndex object with date_range() and feed list of datelabels to loc[[ ]] an error is returned. I never had any problem with a list of indexlabels in loc.
Simple code example (python 3 in Jupyter Notebook):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create DatetimeIndex with date_range()
dates=pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", end="2020-01-10", freq="D", name="datum")

#Check type and dtype: all OK
display(dates.dtype)
display(type(dates))
display(np.dtype('datetime64[ns]') == np.dtype('<M8[ns]'))#returns True on my machine

#create Serie s and DataFrame df with data in 'values' column
values=[100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000]
s=pd.Series(data=values,index=dates)
#df=s.to_frame(name="values")# create df from Series s works fine too
df=pd.DataFrame(data=values, index=dates,columns=["values"])

#display some loc() and iloc() extractions: all OK
display(s,
        df,
        df.loc["2020-01-08"],
        df.iloc[[2,8]],
        df.loc["2020-01-02":"2020-01-08"])
```

So far so good. But when I try to extract with a list of indexlabels:

```
df.loc[['2020-01-02','2020-01-08']]
```

the error: **KeyError: "None of [Index([('2020-01-03', '2020-01-03')], dtype='object', name='datum')] are in the [index]"** is returned. It seem that the dtype has changed from DatetimeIndex object to Object( = str)? I found a workaround on stackoverflow:

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(["2020-01-02","2020-01-08"])
```

but then the indexcolumn name "datum" is dropped. To get the column name back in I assigned df.loc[....] to a variable and reentered the name with the index attribute. So the complete workaround is:

```
var=df.loc[pd.to_datetime(["2020-01-02","2020-01-08"])]
var.index.name="datum"
var
```

To me this seems inconsistent with the way loc[[ ]] works with other indexlabels. Am I missing something?

Comment: Strange. I can't recreate the error with `df.loc[['2020-01-02','2020-01-08']]`

Comment: set_index on the date before slice it using .loc.  In your read_csv you forgot parse_dates=['Date'] parameter